# LPeg how to match an odd integer?

Tags: lpeg

R"09"^0 * S"13579" does not work because R"09"^0 will consume all digits and S"13579" will have nothing to match.

Comment: I find this can work P{
 "Odd",
 Odd = R"09" * V"Odd" + S"1357",
} Is There any better way?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, `odd <- [0-9] odd / [1357]` is correct enough to match small numbers. Alternatively, you could first check it's not last digit of an odd number, before consuming it:

```lua
odd <- (!([1357] ![0-9]) [0-9])* [1357]
```